# Eventstore db GRPC unable to appendToStream

Tags: eventstoredb

trying out eventstoredb and unable to do the most basic thing. is it broken?
the issue is that the client.appendToStream() is blocking and never returns.

started code up with

```
docker run --name esdb-node -it -p 2113:2113 -p 1113:1113     eventstore/eventstore:latest --insecure --run-projections=All  --enable-atom-pub-over-http
```

then the maven dependency of

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.eventstore</groupId>
        <artifactId>db-client-java</artifactId>
        <version>5.3.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

sample code

```
    EventStoreDBClientSettings setts =
            EventStoreDBConnectionString.parseOrThrow("esdb://localhost:2113?tls=false&tlsVerifyCert=false");
    EventStoreDBClient client = EventStoreDBClient.create(setts);

    AccountCreated event = new AccountCreated();
    JsonMapper jsonMapper = new JsonMapper();
    event.setId(UUID.randomUUID().toString());
    event.setLogin("test");

    EventData eventData = EventData
            .builderAsJson("AccountCreated", jsonMapper.writeValueAsBytes(event))
            .build();

    client.appendToStream("some-stream", eventData)
            .get();

    System.out.println("This never happens");
```

**--EDIT--**

**downgrade maven dependency to 5.2.0 and its working**

Comment: Seems to be related to this https://github.com/EventStore/EventStoreDB-Client-Java/issues/267

Answer (score 0):

This was a bug affecting Maven projects depending on version `5.3.1` of the Java Client.

A patch has been applied to fix the issue in version `5.3.2`, more information on the bug is available here: https://github.com/EventStore/EventStoreDB-Client-Java/issues/267.